# What's the difference between an 'empty' list (ar[5]={} )and 'no-list-at-all' (ar[5]) in array initialisation in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, aggregation, array-initialization

I'm just a beginner in C++. In my textbook it is stated that, "if the number of initial values is less than the size of the array, they will be stored in the elements starting from the first position and the remaining positions will be initialised with zero, in case of numeric data types." So I was just curious about the below two situations and was confused about the results:

1.

```
int num[5]={};
for(i=0;i<5;++i)
cout<<num[i]; //result: '00000'
```

2. 

```
int num[5];
for(i=0;i<5;++i)
cout<<num[i]; //result: some garbage values
```

In both the above cases, I didn't input any values to the elements (or I hope so). But why the second case didn't print zeros though?

Comment: In your second case, you do no initialisation.

Comment: The first one is called "value initialization". The values are set to 0 by default. In the second one, the values are uninitialized and random garbage remains. You can try  the same with most types.

Comment: The second doesn't have an initializer with fewer initial values.  It has no initializer at all, so nothing is initialized.

Comment: so, it means that it only works for value initialisation. Thank you gentle men, for teaching me something new today. It was so simple :)